# How can I get a save file from a PSOne game (played at PS3), into my PS Vita?

Tags: ps3, ps-vita, psone-classics

I played a lot of PSOne games in my PS3, and have in mind to get a PS Vita to play them again, so I want to know if I can reuse my FF VIII save data, or I have to play the game again, for example.

Thanks!

---

**[EDIT]**
Worked just like @Bryan C said, but you need to have the game previously installed (as it creates the respective save file into PS Vita's memcard), because you have to choose a save file when you are getting the data from PS3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you just need to copy the save file straight to the Vita from your PS3.

(First verify you have the correct memory card and make note of it's nickname, these first two steps are optional)

1) On the PS3 go to your virtual PS1 memory card.

2) Open the memory card and find your game save.

3) Connect your Vita to your PS3 and in the Content Manager on the Vita select "PS3 System -> PS Vita System"

4) Select "Saved Data / PlayStation"

5) You will see the option to select a PS1 virtual memory card

6) Select the card you want and it will open showing all of the saves inside

7) Select the save file you want and copy it over. That should do the trick.

Comment: I edited the question, in case of other people have the same question. Thank you!

Comment: Cool, and I modified the lead to the question to drop the cloud stuff out since it's not in the question anymore.